# написать функцию, которая проверяет, является ли заданное вещественное число формата float числом, меньшим по абсолютной величине единицы

Tags: java, float

Написать функцию, которая проверяет, является ли заданное вещественное число формата float числом, меньшим по абсолютной величине единицы. Функция не должна использовать операции сравнения вещественных чисел, вместо этого используйте операции с битами и целыми числами, а также функции, превращающие вещественное число в битовое представление в виде целого - Float.floatToIntBits().

сначала написал так:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    System.out.println(lessThenOne (-0.314f));
}

public static boolean lessThenOne(float number) {
    boolean lessThanOne = ((byte) number == 0);
    return lessThanOne;
}
```

но приведение вещественного к целому с помощью (byte), во-первых, включает в себя запрещенные для этого задания операции с вещественными, а во-вторых, не всегда будет давать корректный результат для больших значений аргумента, как мне написать с функцией Float.floatToIntBits()?

Comment: дайте, пожалуйста, вопросу осмысленный заголовок (нажав [edit])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если изучить формат представления вещественных чисел [IEEE 754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), то легко заметить, что меньше единицы по модулю те числа, 8 битов которых (с 23 по 31) образуют число меньше 127.

Почему так? Числа в формате `знак * 1.мантисса * 2^порядок`, где порядок хранится в байте, значение которого смещёно на 127. Таким образом, для чисел от единицы и выше (в т.ч. +-Infinity) порядок будет 127 и более, а для чисел менее единицы (в т.ч. денормализованных) 0..126

Вот пример на Delphi. Сдвиг вправо, наложение маски для удаления знака.

```
var
  i: Int32;
  f: Single;
begin
  f := 0.99;
  i := PInteger(@f)^;
  if ((i shr 23) and $FF) < 127 then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('less');
```

Раз у Вас в Java есть функция получения целочисленного представления внутреннего содержания float, то выделить нужные биты не составит труда.
Проверим на [Ideone](https://ideone.com/E7PvTq)

```
float f = -0.99f;
int ii = Float.floatToIntBits(f);
System.out.println(((ii >> 23) & 0xFF) < 127);
```